# How to generate grand total dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

here i want to create dynamically grand total. i got total of price and quantity. but i cant get grand total to total, so kindly request to solve this, here i have to use php for loop for ten row

```js
function myFunction(time,v) {
var p="price"+time;
var d="demo"+time;
var y = document.getElementById(p).value;
var z = v;
var ans=y*z;
document.getElementById(d).value = ans;
}
function my(time,ans) {
//alert('You have not Login  !!');
var p="demo"+time;
var y = document.getElementById(p).value;
 //var z=y+ans;
 document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = ans;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <?php
 $i=0;
     while($i<=10)
       {
     ?>
    <tr>     
   <td> <input id="price<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text" readonly value="5"></td>
   <td><input id="qty" type="number" value="0"  onChange="myFunction(<?php echo $i; ?>,this.value)" ></td>
  <td><input id="demo<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text" value="0"  onChange="my(<?php echo $i; ?>,this.value)" >
      
      </td>
</tr>     
 <?php 
 $i++; 
 }?>

<h4> Total :- <span id = "total"></span></h4>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your **Total count** *globaly*, and Get all *elements of your "**demo**"* by **querySelector** and then calculate them.

Check snippest.

```js
var _mytotal=0;
function _Function1(time,v)
{
 var p="price"+time;
 var d="demo"+time;
 var y = document.getElementById(p).value;
 var z = v;
 var ans=y*z;
 document.getElementById(d).value = ans;
 _mytotal=0;
 _Function2();
}
function _Function2()
{
 var demos = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="demo"]');
 demos.forEach(_FunctionTotal);
}
function _FunctionTotal(item) 
{
    _mytotal = +_mytotal + +document.getElementById(item.id).value;
    document.getElementById("total").textContent = _mytotal;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>  
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Quantity</th>
  <th>Total</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input id="price0" type="text" readonly value="5"></td>
  <td><input id="qty" type="number" value="0" onChange="_Function1(0,this.value)" ></td>
  <td><input id="demo0" type="text" readonly value="0" ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input id="price1" type="text" readonly value="5"></td>
  <td><input id="qty" type="number" value="0" onChange="_Function1(1,this.value)" ></td>
  <td><input id="demo1" type="text" readonly value="0" ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input id="price2" type="text" readonly value="5"></td>
  <td><input id="qty" type="number" value="0" onChange="_Function1(2,this.value)" ></td>
  <td><input id="demo2" type="text" readonly value="0" ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input id="price3" type="text" readonly value="5"></td>
  <td><input id="qty" type="number" value="0" onChange="_Function1(3,this.value)" ></td>
  <td><input id="demo3" type="text" readonly value="0" ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input id="price4" type="text" readonly value="5"></td>
  <td><input id="qty" type="number" value="0" onChange="_Function1(4,this.value)" ></td>
  <td><input id="demo4" type="text" readonly value="0" ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><h4>Grand Total</h4></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><h4><span id = "total"></span></h4></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: “Store your **Total count** _globaly_”—horrible advice.